# How to move color boxs in vs code editor to old place as android studio?

Tags: colors, visual-studio-code

The color boxs was at edge the file as anyother editor but now its moved between my code.

How can I removed to old place?

for more declare see the picture please, thank you.
Screen of my editor:
[image]

Comment: Is there ever a time when you'd have colors twice in a line? Did you look to see when this was changed, checking the changelogs? Have you searched settings?

Comment: @music2myear I do not remember when it change so iI do not know the changelogs. i did serach in settings no luck